# 2D plotting library with LGPL

Tags: c++, qt, 2d

What would be the most appropriate choice to plot simple 2D charts in a Qt application (C++), given a set of points with some basic capability of interacting with the plot (zoom, pan, picking)?

Similar to Qt Charts but with a LGPL License

[image]

Comment: Questions asking for software recommendations are [off-topic on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Have you considered asking this on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only two LGPL options I know off:

- Qwt, as mentioned by the other poster
- Embedded a HTML page into your Qt application with [Qt WebEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html) and then use a HTML charting library like [D3](https://d3js.org/). Due to the heavier performance requirements of HTML/JS, this is not an option if you target low-end devices, otherwise it should work fine. You can export data needed by the charts from C++ to JS with [Qt WebChannel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-index.html).

There are also some options that are dual-licensed with a commercial license and GPL, which for a closed source project usually means you have to buy a license:

- [KDChart](https://wiki.kdab.com/display/Products/KDChart) (GPLv2+/Commercial)
- [QCustomPlot](http://qcustomplot.com/) (GPLv3/Commercial)
- [QtCharts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html) (GPLv3/Commercial)

Answer (score 2):

Qwt seems to be a solid alternative. It uses a Qwt License which is basically LGPL. Works quite seamlessly with Qt too.

http://qwt.sourceforge.net/